# How can I get rangeslider.js to work on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem, you will see I have a web page where I implement the rangeslider plugin on PC it works correctly but on mobile I can't explain myself: when on mobile I select the slider I cannot make it go up or down or change the amount it has, it is only modified while The scroll is used but as you know with the scroll the user moves on mobile, therefore it cannot work so check what I mean on the page

this is the link of the page: http://ucreativa.work/linux/nsite2/product.php

As you can see, it works well on PC, but if they try to use it on mobile, the slider does not work.

What do you think that might be? I append the js code that I use I don't append the css because it is a lot of code that is not relevant

my question is can this plugin work on mobile?

```js
var cpu_cur_val = '2';
var ram_cur_val = '4';
var disk_cur_val = '8';
var backup_cur_val = '30';
var ips_cur_val = '0';

function new_range (wrapper) {
    // Variables to use later
    var rangeWrapper = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__wrapper');
    var rangeInput = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__input');
    var rangeValues = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__values');
    var rangeValueNumberBottom = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__value__number--bottom');
    var rangeValueTextBottom = document.querySelector('.' + wrapper + '__value__text--bottom');
    var rangeSliderPaths = document.querySelectorAll('.' + wrapper + '__slider__path');
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var mouseInitialY = 0;
    var mouseDy = 0;
    var mouseDyLimit = 25;
    var mouseDyFactor = 3;
    var max = parseInt(rangeInput.max);
    var rangeMin = parseInt(rangeInput.min);
    var rangeMax = parseInt(rangeInput.max);
    var rangeValue = parseInt(rangeInput.value);
    var rangeHeight = 320;
    var currentY = rangeHeight * rangeValue / max;
    var rangeMinY = rangeHeight * rangeMin / max;
    var rangeMaxY = rangeHeight * rangeMax / max;
    var scaleMax = 0.32;
    var scale, newPath, newY, newSliderY, lastMouseDy, rangeWrapperLeft, pageX, pageY;

    // Update slider value, initially using the `input` value
    updateValue();

    // Function to build the slider `path`, using the given `dy` and `ty` values
    function buildPath(dy, ty) {
        return 'M 0 ' + ty + ' q ' + mouseX + ' ' + dy + ' 120 0 l 0 320 l -120 0 Z';
    }

    // Function to update the slider value
    function updateValue() {


        // Clear animations if are still running
        anime.remove([rangeValues, rangeSliderPaths[0], rangeSliderPaths[1]]);

        // Calc the `input` value using the current `y`
        rangeValue = parseInt(currentY * max / rangeHeight);

        // Calc `scale` value for numbers
        scale = (rangeValue - rangeMin) / (rangeMax - rangeMin) * scaleMax;
        // Update `input` value
        rangeInput.value = rangeValue;
        // rangeSum.innerText = rangeValue;
        rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = rangeValue;
        // Match the javascript value to real input value;
        rangeInput.setAttribute('value', rangeValue);

        switch (wrapper) {
          default:
            rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'cpu':
            cpu_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'ram':
            if (rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText == '0') {
              rangeValueTextBottom.innerText = 'זיכרון (MB)';
              rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = '500';
            } else {
              rangeValueTextBottom.innerText = 'זיכרון (GB)';
            }
            ram_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'disk':
            rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = rangeValue + '0';
            disk_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'backup':
            if (rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText == '0') {
              rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = '0';
            } else {
              rangeValueNumberBottom.innerText = rangeValue + '0';
            }
            backup_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
          case 'ips':
            ips_cur_val = rangeValue;
            break;
        }

        // Some maths calc
        if (Math.abs(mouseDy) < mouseDyLimit) {
            lastMouseDy = mouseDy;
        } else {
            lastMouseDy = mouseDy < 0 ? -mouseDyLimit : mouseDyLimit;
        }

        // Calc the `newSliderY` value to build the slider `path`
        newSliderY = currentY + lastMouseDy / mouseDyFactor;
        if (newSliderY < rangeMinY || newSliderY > rangeMaxY) {
            newSliderY = newSliderY < rangeMinY ? rangeMinY : rangeMaxY;
        }

        // Build `path` string and update `path` elements
        newPath = buildPath(lastMouseDy, rangeHeight - newSliderY);
        rangeSliderPaths[0].setAttribute('d', newPath);
        rangeSliderPaths[1].setAttribute('d', newPath);
    }

    // Function to simulate the elastic behavior
    function elasticRelease() {
        // Morph the paths to the opposite direction, to simulate a strong elasticity
        anime({
            targets: rangeSliderPaths,
            d: buildPath(-lastMouseDy * 1.3, rangeHeight - (currentY - lastMouseDy / mouseDyFactor)),
            duration: 150,
            easing: 'linear',
            complete: function () {
                // Morph the paths to the normal state, using the `elasticOut` easing function (default)
                anime({
                    targets: rangeSliderPaths,
                    d: buildPath(0, rangeHeight - currentY),
                    duration: 4000,
                    elasticity: 880
                });
            }
        });

    }

    // Handle `mousedown` and `touchstart` events, saving data about mouse position
    function mouseDown(e) {
        mouseY = mouseInitialY = e.targetTouches ? e.targetTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
        rangeWrapperLeft = rangeWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    }

    // Handle `mousemove` and `touchmove` events, calculating values to morph the slider `path` and translate values properly
    function mouseMove(e) {
        if (mouseY) {
            pageX = e.targetTouches ? e.targetTouches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
            pageY = e.targetTouches ? e.targetTouches[0].pageY : e.pageY;
            mouseX = pageX - rangeWrapperLeft;
            mouseDy = (pageY - mouseInitialY) * mouseDyFactor;
            newY = currentY + mouseY - pageY;
            // alert(newY);
            if (newY >= rangeMinY && newY <= rangeMaxY) {
                currentY = newY;
                mouseY = pageY;
            } else {
                currentY = newY < rangeMinY ? rangeMinY : rangeMaxY;
            }
            // After doing maths, update the value
            updateValue();
        }
    }

    // Handle `mouseup`, `mouseleave` and `touchend` events
    function mouseUp() {
        // Trigger elastic animation in case `y` value has changed
        if (mouseDy) {
            elasticRelease();
        }
        // Reset values
        mouseY = mouseDy = 0;
    }

    // Events listeners
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('touchstart', mouseDown);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('touchmove', mouseMove);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseUp);
    rangeWrapper.addEventListener('touchend', mouseUp);
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a sufficiently technical diagnosis of the problem. This is a lot of code to review. Where do you think the problem is? What can you remove and still have the problem persist?